Path overlaps nodes in TikZ
I am trying to draw a sort of 'locally complete' graph. I know my code is a little ugly, I do not need something very neat, but this appearance is a little upsetting.
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=0.5pt]

\foreach \x in {1,...,32}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{360/32*(\x-1)}
    \node[draw,circle,radius=1.3cm] (A-\x) at (\result:37cm) {};
    
    
\foreach \x in {1,...,32}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{360/32*(\x-1) + 360/32/2}
    \node[draw,circle,radius=1.3cm] (B-\x) at (\result:32cm) {};
    

  \foreach \from/\to in {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,6/7,7/8,8/9,9/10,10/11,11/12,12/13,
  13/14,14/15,15/16,16/17,17/18,18/19,19/20,20/21,21/22,
  22/23,23/24,24/25,25/26,26/27,27/28,28/29,29/30,30/31,
  31/32,32/1}{
    \path (A-\from) edge [-] (A-\to);
    \path (B-\from) edge [-] (B-\to);
    }
    
    \foreach \e in {1,...,32}{
    \path (A-\e) edge [-] (B-\e);
    }    
    
    \foreach \e in {1,...,31}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro\result{\e+1}
    \path (A-\result) edge [-] (B-\e);
    }
    
    \path (A-1) edge [-] (B-32);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

At some nodes, the paths overlap the circles. I do not really know how to avoid it efficiently. And idea?

Please provide a complete MWE. Also, can you please give an example of exactly what you want?

There was a part of the code missing. I would like a graph made from to circles of nodes. Each node is connected to two neighbors in the circle it belongs to, and then connected to two nodes from the other circle.

I'm not sure if this answers your question, because I'm not sure where you see overlapping, but you could combine your loops to cycle through things more efficiently. In particular, you can replace the need to specify the long list of pairs by hand.
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture} [line width=0.5pt]
    \foreach \x 
    [evaluate=\x as \i using {360/32*(\x-1)},%
    evaluate=\i as \j using {\i+360/32/2},%
    remember=\x as \xlast (initially \pi),%
    ] in {1,...,32}
    {
      \node[draw,circle,radius=1.3cm] (A-\x) at (\i:37cm) {};
      \node[draw,circle,radius=1.3cm] (B-\x) at (\j:32cm) {};
      \ifnum\xlast=\pi\else \draw (A-\xlast) -- (A-\x) (B-\xlast) -- (B-\x)
      (A-\x) -- (B-\xlast);\fi
      \draw (A-\x) -- (B-\x);
    }
    \draw (A-32) -- (A-1) (B-32) -- (B-1) (A-1) -- (B-32);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Here's a low-resolution image which will not look good, but won't exhaust memory and crash my editor:


Indeed, a part of the code was missing, sorry. I think this version would do. Anyway, thank you for the cleaner way to write this code!

@Hmart I don't get edges overlapping (see edit above) when I add in the additional connections with this version. Is this what you want or should the edges be crossing? I'm not sure if I've connected the correct nodes ....

Probably you want the following:
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs.standard}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\num{32}
  \graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=5cm, empty nodes, n=\num] {
    subgraph C_n [name=inner] --
    subgraph C_n [name=outer]
  };

  \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \y using {int(mod(\x,\num)+1)}] in {1,...,\num}
    \draw (outer \x) -- (inner \y) (outer \y) -- (inner \x);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Yes, that's the idea. However, some paths go over some nodes, which is ugly in my opinion. The code proposed by @cfr works perfectly.

Yes, it is ugly. I missed an int in the expression. See the updated answer.

Now it is nice too, thank you!
